# stop overlap third div

Tags: html, css

im new to css , i did write code below :

```css
.topcenter {

 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 position: relative;
}
.back {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 position: absolute;
 
}
.green {
 background-color: #9AC149;
 }
```

```html
    <div class="back"><img src="https://www.smashingmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/10-dithering-opt.jpg" width="500" height="200" alt=""/></div>
  <div class="topcenter"><a href="register.html" target="_self"><img src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/buttons/buttons_PNG44.png?i=1" alt="" width="10%" title="register"/></a></div>
  <div class="green">
    <div class="row row1">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div><p>
        i dont want it be overlap
        </p>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Content for New Div Tag Goes Here</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div><img src="images/book.png" width="413" height="461" alt=""/></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

problem is row1 overlap first image but i want just register button overlap image , i did try "clear:both;" in row1 css but nothing happened . what should i do ?

Comment: i didn't get you problem can u share both screen shot 
what is prob? and what you wont?

Comment: It's really hard to tell what the code is doing because all the images are broken.  Could you insert some valid image URLs?  Then we could see the problem you are describing.

Comment: i copied you code i didn't understand what you want?
tell me what you want other draw your requirement. i will solve

Comment: i did edit it please try copy again you understand ... green background go behind image that i dont want and i want green background start after image

Comment: here it is : https://jsfiddle.net/jhyk3478/

Comment: So you want this:  https://jsfiddle.net/rw6L7puw/1/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly the problem is with using position: absolute.
To put it simply if you use it on part of your page that that part is out of order of elements on your page. It doesn't take place. So you can just give it other kind of display.

```
.back {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
}
```

and if you want to place your button over your image you should add `position: absolute` to your `.topcenter` class. You can move it with `top,right,bottom,left`.

You can try to work it out with order of your files too.